# Automated jQuery Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

today I was implementing jQuery Progress-bars on a web-page. I needed to implement about 30 progress bars on the same page.

Its code goes like this

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
value: 80
});
```

which displays a progress bar 80% full on the below div

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Now what happened is, I have to mention 30 different progressbar divs and then call them to run using 30 jquery calls...

Instead

What I tried was

```
<div id="progressbar" title="54"></div>
```

with a call as

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
value: $(this).attr('title')
});
```

which should automatically give the value to the title of that div...

albeit this does not work...

anyone have a clue as to what is wrong here?

I also tried

```
$( "#progressbar" ).each( function(){
progressbar({
value: 80
});
});
```

Still no-go

Can anyone gimme a tip here... Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out. Cheers!

It works like this

```
<div class="progressbar" rel="54"></div>
```

and then call like

```
            $("div.progressbar").each (function () {
                var element = this;
                $(element).progressbar({
                value: parseInt($(element).attr("rel"))
                });
            });
```

Cheers to @volkan-er who answered it here - [JQuery UI: multiple progress bar - problems to set dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116673/jquery-ui-multiple-progress-bar-problems-to-set-dynamic-values)

:)